# How to find the 3rd coordinate of a triangle

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry, equation

This is not homework. We are trying to build double connection lines between circles for a project.

Given a triangle of any type (because it will be rotated)

- AB is known
- AC is known
- BC is known Where
- AB is equal to BC (they are both the radius of the circle)

Point A is (x1,y1) and is known. It is the center point of the circle.
Point B is (x2,y2) and is known. It is the point on the edge of the circle that connects to the center of a remote circle.

Point C is unknown (x3,y3) and is what we are trying to figure out.  I THINK we need to use the law of cosines, but it's not working out so far.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Question would probably be more at home at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if AB is equal to BC (they are both the radius of the circle) then A is centre of circle. Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

You have much more info than you need to get the answer and it has nothing to do with law of cosine

Basically you only need A, B, AC, and BC

1. You draw a circle with A as the center and AC as the edge
2. You draw another circle with B as the center and BC as the edge

These two circles will have two intersecting points, and they are the two possible location of C

put it in math:

you have two Binary quadratic equations:

- (x-x1)^2 + (y-y1)^2 = AC^2
- (x-x2)^2 + (y-y2)^2 = BC^2

and you need to get (x, y) from these two equations

Comment: So this is where I got caught up earlier. I'm drawing a blank at
sqrt(BC^2 - (y-y2)^2) + x2 = sqrt(AC^2 - (y-y1)^2) - x1
I need to solve for Y here, but I'm failing to do so. I know algebra fail. I forget how sqrts distribute over terms.

Comment: @SeanClark ok then this is a pure math problem.. i think http://math.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to discuss this

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is usually good for this sort of thing, but it comes up with a pretty nasty expression for this ( http://tinyurl.com/cj7at7q ).

Comment: @ChrisJohnson haha.. we are spoiled by this kind of tools..

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use the law of cosines, since you know the lengths of the three sides of the triangle (AB), (BC) and (AC). The law of cosines states that

```
(BC)^2 = (AC)^2 + (AB)^2 - 2 (AC)(AB) cos theta
```

where theta is the internal angle of the triangle at vertex A. Rearranging this gives

```
theta = acos(((BC)^2 - (AC)^2 - (AB)^2)/(-2 (AC)(AB)))
```

then your answer is (in vector notation):

```
(x,y) = (x1,y1) + (AC)*(v1,v2)
```

where `(v1,v2)` is the unit vector in the direction from A to C. (*i.e.*, in scalar notation, `x=x1+(AC)*v1` and `y=y1+(AC)*v2`). We can obtain v1 and v2 by rotating the unit vector from A to B by the angle theta:

```
v1 = (cos(theta)*(x2-x1) + sin(theta)*(y2-y1))/(AB)
v2 = (cos(theta)*(y2-y1) - sin(theta)*(x2-x1))/(AB)
```

Flip the sign of theta to get the other of the two solutions.

Note that one can avoid ever calculating theta by observing that:

```
cos(theta) = ((BC)^2 - (AC)^2 - (AB)^2)/(-2 (AC)(AB))
sin(theta) = sqrt(1-((BC)^2 - (AC)^2 - (AB)^2)/(-2 (AC)(AB))^2)
```

which may be faster to evaluate than the trigonometric functions.

Comment: So in Javascript the v1 and v2 part I have this... var v1 = (Math.cos(theta) * (x2 - x1) + Math.sin(theta) * (y1 - y1)) / AB;
var v2 = (Math.cos(theta) * (y2 - y1) + Math.sin(theta) * (x2 - x1)) / AB;  However, how do I translate your (x,y) = (x1,y1) + (AC)*(v1,v2) part into JavaScript?  The commas inside the parens are confusing me.  So would I do something like... var x = x1 + AC * v1; var y = y1 + AC * v2; ?

Comment: @Allen -[So would I do something like... var x = x1 + AC * v1; var y = y1 + AC * v2;]- That's right. The commas inside parens are vector notation, which I've now clarified in the answer.